# Unable to resolve action back2code/ssh-key-to-gitsecret, repository not found

Tags: github, github-actions

```yaml
name: Generate and save SSH key
 
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
 
jobs:
  generate-ssh-key:
    runs-on: [ atc-ubuntu-latest ]
 
    steps:
      - name: Generate SSH Key
        id: ssh-key-gen
        run: |
          ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "ffff@example.com" -f ssh_key -q -N ""
          public_key=$(cat ssh_key.pub)
          echo "$public_key"
 
      - name : Create/Update Secrets
        uses: back2code/ssh-key-to-gitsecret@v0.0.1
        with:
          name: BITBUCKET_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
          keyfilename: ssh_key
          pa_token: ${{ secrets.PA_TOKEN }}
```

I created a personal access token and kept it as secret named as `PA_TOKEN`. With `atc-ubuntu-latest` this it doesn't even start when I change it to `ubuntu-latest` it says:

> Unable to resolve action back2code/ssh-key-to-gitsecret, repository not found

Comment: https://github.com/back2code/ssh-key-to-gitsecret doesn't exist. Where did you get it from?

Comment: it was in the documentation,is it possible it's private ?

Comment: Yes, looks like it as it's not accessible publicly.